# Acces variable set in parent constructor from child function

Tags: php

There are already many threads about this kind of problem, but for some reason i can't get it to work.

In TestClass::test(), $db is NULL.

The $db value is set in App construct and I'm trying to recover that value from an extended class function. (so i don't need to set $db everytime everywhere).

Some help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

> File : index.php

```
<?php     
   include('classes/App.class.php');
   $oApp = new App();
   echo TestClass::test();
?>
```

> File : App.class.php

```
<?php
class App {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct () {
        include_once("CAutoLoader.class.php");
        $oCAutoLoader = new CAutoLoader();

        $this->db = "someValue";
    }
}
?>
```

> File : TestClass.class.php

```
<?php
class TestClass extends App
{
    function __construct () {
    }

    public static function test () {
        return $db;
    }
}
?>
```

> File : CAutoLoader.class.php

```
<?php
class CAutoLoader {
    CONST CLASS_EXTENSION = '.class.php';

    public function __construct () {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
    }

    private function loader ($className) {
        include $className . self::CLASS_EXTENSION;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: In class App , change `$db` to static property and in the constructor change this `$this->db = "someValue";` to `self::$db = "someValue";`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `this` in your `TestClass` and a static method cannot access non-static properties. Remove the `static` keyword and return the right value.

```
public function test() {
    return $this->db;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you meant to retrieve the instance of the `db` via a static method you **must** declare the variable as static.

```
class App {
    protected static $db = 'hey';
    ...
}

class TestCase extends App {
    public static function test() {
        return parent::$db;
    }
}

echo TestCase::test(); // returns hey
```

Comment: Yes, it works if i do : 
$CTestClass = new TestClass;  
echo $CTestClass ->test();
But i can't directly call TestClass::test(); (using $this when not in object context)

Comment: I tried as you told, but i still have the "using $this when not in object context" issue. Something must be missing, but i don't know what. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, your method works but as i said, i'm trying to set $db value in constructor. I will keep searching for a way. Thanks !

Comment: @WerdZerg in that case you need to call the parent constructor with `super()` in your child class. Otherwise the parent constructor will never be executed